# 0x Bad request error

Tags: 0x

since a few days, I am receiving a Bad Request error (status code 400) when trying to sign and submit an order:

```
ERROR(status code 400): {
  "code": 100,
  "reason": "Validation Failed",
  "validationErrors": [
    {
      "field": "",
      "code": 1001,
      "reason": "should be array"
    }
  ]
}
```

I haven't changed anything in the code and it was working before. I observed this behavior on Ropsten and Polygon. status.0x.org shows that there is a major incident on Ethereum, but not on the other two mentioned networks.

Can someone from the 0x team help please?

```
const utils = require("@0x/protocol-utils");
const contractAddresses = require("@0x/contract-addresses");

function Sign() {
    
    async function sign() {
        
        const CHAIN_ID = 3; 
        const NULL_ADDRESS = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        const addresses = contractAddresses.getContractAddressesForChainOrThrow(CHAIN_ID);
    
        // Calculate value for order expiry parameter (here: 50 minutes)
        const getFutureExpiryInSeconds = () =>
        Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000 + 3000000).toString();
    
        // Unlock MetaMask
        const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: "eth_requestAccounts"
        });

        // Use currently connected MetaMask account as the maker account
        const maker = accounts[0];
        console.log("Maker address: " + maker)
    
        
        const order = new utils.LimitOrder({
            makerToken: "0xc03ce38bc55836a4ef61ab570253cd7bfff3af44", 
            takerToken: "0xad6d458402f60fd3bd25163575031acdce07538d", 
            makerAmount: "1000", 
            takerAmount: "1000", 
            maker: maker,
            expiry: getFutureExpiryInSeconds(),
            salt: Date.now().toString(),
            chainId: CHAIN_ID,
            verifyingContract: addresses.exchangeProxy, 
            takerTokenFeeAmount: "0",
            sender: NULL_ADDRESS,
            feeRecipient: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        });
        
        console.dir(order);

        // Sign order conforming to the EIP712 standard
        const signature = await order.getSignatureWithProviderAsync(
            window.ethereum, 
            utils.SignatureType.EIP712 
        );
        console.log(`Signature: ${JSON.stringify(signature, undefined, 2)}`);

        // Append signature object to order object for the post of the order
        const signedOrder = { ...order, signature };
        console.log(signedOrder)

        const resp = await fetch("https://ropsten.api.0x.org/orderbook/v1/order", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(signedOrder),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        });
    
        // Handle response
        if (resp.status === 200) {
            alert("Successfully posted order to SRA");
        } else {
            const body = await resp.json();
            alert(
                `ERROR(status code ${resp.status}): ${JSON.stringify(body, undefined, 2)}`
            )
        }
    }
    
      return (
          <button onClick={sign}>Sign and submit</button>
      );
    
  }
  
  export default Sign;`
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this issue. Our teams are actively investigating why these 400s are showing up on Ropsten Orderbook. Will circle back when we understand more.